# Read/write in Global Memory of an OpenCL Kernel

Tags: arrays, kernel, opencl, shared-memory

I followed this page for many time, I consider that it is one of the best pages for questions ofprograming in general.

Well, normally I alway try to find a solution for my problems but now I think that I need some help of the comunity because I don't know how to resolve my problem.

The problem that I have is with the OpenCL API. I need to program a Kernel that adds some values in 'global memory'. A brief 
description of the problem is:

- I have an array of 'index' the size N.
- I have an array of 'values 'the size N.
- I have an array of 'adds' the size M.
- The array of index contains the index of the array 'adds'. For example, if the first value of the array of index is 3, then the first value of the array 
  of 'values' is add to the index 3 of the array of 'adds'.

The problem is that I have N threads (one for each index/value) that read/write in gobal memory simultanious and they can read/write in the same location, then the final value is inconsistent

I added an image to see the problem graphically:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzQ4sqg5hAdnMXZlZlIzUFB4QkhQOXZXVjcyS1ZKdXZYTS1j/view?usp=docslist_api

You have any idea?

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: I think having M threads is more appropiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, check out OpenCL atomic functions: https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/atomicFunctions.html